antlr4 grammar - perf issues, ambiguities, and loads of single-char tokens
I am writing an antl4 grammar for splitting semicolon-separated statements. Below is a minimal version of the grammar. The full grammar has multiple types of comments, strings, identifiers, etc.
The parser "works" in terms of correctness, but I am running into serious performance issues. I am not sure if its because of ambiguities or just because each individual CHAR gets tokenized, which leads to massive parse trees for even medium-sized inputs.
I referenced this similar post, but I dont think it is right for my use case because CHAR is not "unknown". This other post suggests its not possible to group CHARs without a delimiter, which makes sense, so maybe I need some sort of delimiter rule?
FWIW, I tried switching the prediction mode to SLL and it made the parser 100x faster, and the tree was correct for many different inputs. But I am not sure if I will be shooting myself in the foot down the road if I dont fully understand the problem here and just switch to SLL and pray.
Any help or guidance is much appreciated!
grammar Splitter;

options { caseInsensitive = true; }

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

rootNode
    : chunk* EOF
    ;

chunk
    : statement ';'?
    ;

statement 
    : (COMMENT | CHAR)+
    ;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

COMMENT
    : '/*' .*? '*/'
    ;

CHAR 
    : ~';' 
    ;

WS
    : [ \r\n\t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;


SAMPLE INPUT:
abc;/* ; */def;ghi;
PARSE TREE:

PROFILER OUTPUT:


Your grammar is ambiguous because it cannot decide where one "chunk" ends and the next one begins. You can't expect any parser to get this right because your grammar is bad; Antlr tries to make the best of if anyways. Don't make the ';' optional.

thanks @kaby76 ! I changed chunk rule to statement (';' | EOF), and all of the ambiguity disappeared :)

PS. I don't know why this question was downvoted. The question was unambiguous and to the point. Further, there is a pitiful amount of information on debugging Antlr grammars. I have spent years toiling over ambiguity and fallback optimization in the 300+ grammars in grammars-v4, trying to clean up the mess. We need more questions like this to explain how to solve these types of problems in an algorithmic manner, not by guessing.
